# JSDoc reference function in object literal (CommonJS module.exports)

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm writing a CommonJS module and have all of my methods defined as function definitions within the module. Those methods are then defined in the `module.exports` object. This is all written with es6 as well.

However, with my annotations, the generated documentation only links to the object definition and does not display the actual documentation for the methods.

```
// file named utils.js
const regular = require('regular');
const isEmpty = require('lodash.isempty);

/**
 * @memberof utils
 * @param {object} obj The value to check if it is an object or not
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isTrueObject(obj) {
    return !Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj === 'object' && !isEmpty(obj) ;
}
/**
 * @memberof utils
 * @param {*} val
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNumberLike(val) {
    return isNumber(val) || regular.number.test(val);
}

/**
 * @module utils
 */
module.exports = {
    isTrueObject,
    isNumberLike
};
```

If i keep the `module.exports` property names as-is, no docs get generated, except for a blank page for `utils`:

[image: blank documentation page]

I have to do the following to get the proper documentation:

```
// file named utils.js
const regular = require('regular');
const isEmpty = require('lodash.isempty);

/**
 * @memberof utils
 * @param {object} obj The value to check if it is an object or not
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isTrueObject(obj) {
    return !Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj === 'object' && !isEmpty(obj) ;
}
/**
 * @memberof utils
 * @param {*} val
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNumberLike(val) {
    return isNumber(val) || regular.number.test(val);
}

/**
 * @module utils
 */
module.exports = {
    /**
     * @function
     * @param {object} obj The value to check if it is an object or not
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isTrueObject,
    /**
     * @function
     * @param {*} val
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isNumberLike
};
```

This clearly is not ideal since the documentation is not right next above the actual function declaration and this easily leads to duplication of documentation. Is there a different way to link these and generate the same documentation?

[image: proper documentation output]

I tried the following but all i got were links to the code itself and no actual documentation output:

```
/**
 * @module utils
 */
module.exports = {
    /** @see module:utils#isTrueObject */
    isTrueObject,
    /** @borrows isNumberLike as isNumberLike */
    isNumberLike
};
```

using either `@see` or `@borrow` generates the following:

[image: only links]

This obviously is not the desired output.

Does anyone know how to properly document this without needless duplication?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `@module` declaration at the top of the file and replace `@memberof utils` with `@static` produces the intended result:

```
// file named utils.js
/**
 * @module utils
 */
const regular = require('regular');
const isEmpty = require('lodash.isempty);

/**
 * @static
 * @param {object} obj The value to check if it is an object or not
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isTrueObject(obj) {
    return !Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj === 'object' && !isEmpty(obj) ;
}
/**
 * @static
 * @param {*} val
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isNumberLike(val) {
    return isNumber(val) || regular.number.test(val);
}

module.exports = {
    isTrueObject,
    isNumberLike
};
```